# Using WebElement instead of By - is it possible?

Tags: webdriver, java, selenium-webdriver

In my Java WebDriver test I use method `findElements()` to check if an element is present on the page. 
I use the Page Object Pattern, so the element I want to check is declared in SomePage.class. In my test I would like to just refer to declared element, but method `findElements(`) requires me to use By type and look for the element again.

Is there any way to declare WebElement once and then refer to it in findElements() method?

Comment: The situation also happens with other methods which require By argument but not support WebElement argument. Would be nice to find general solution to problems like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already found the element, why are you looking it up again? Maybe you should not use `findElements()` again, because that will try to find the elements based on a By. It cannot find based on a found element reference.

Maybe just use a `element.IsDisplayed()` instead to check if the element is still available for interaction.

Comment: `element.isDisplayed` actually works. But I have no method `element.exist`, do you use Java?

Comment: Got the exists from this answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18061480/1088584 Maybe it does not work for Java, will remove it from my answer.

Comment: The answer is about C# so maybe C# has exist() method. And what about situation when I want to check if declared element is NOT present. There are no method like `element.isNotDisplayed`. What should I do?

Comment: To check an an element is not displayed you can use this function, but you need to catch the NosuchElementFound exception, when the exception occurs the element is not present. Check this answer for a code example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27853677/1088584

Comment: I knew that solution but I wondered if there are more pretty way or built-in method. Overall thank you for your usefull help.

Answer (score 1):

Would have preferred to comment as it's more of a tip then an answer but need more reputation for that.

A lot of these issues get solved with [Selenide](http://selenide.org/)

You have lot of extra options to interact, or wait for, elements and as it's a skin over Selenium you can still use any Selenium command you'd like.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck!